# boost counting_range doesn't include iterating the last value

Tags: for-loop, boost, for-range

I have this code:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::InitDateTransArrays()
{
    if (theApp.UseTranslationINI() || theApp.GetProgramLanguage() == LANGUAGE_MALAGASY)
    {
        CString strKey;

        // Days of the week
        for (auto const &i : boost::counting_range(0, 7))
        //for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            strKey.Format(_T("Day%d"), i);
            // AJT v17.1.3 Now use our own methods
            m_aryDateTrans[DATE_TRANS_DAY].Add(GetStringFromTranslationINI(_T("Days"), strKey));
            m_aryDateTrans[DATE_TRANS_DAY_SHORT].Add(GetStringFromTranslationINI(_T("DaysAbbreviated"), strKey));
        }

        // Months of the year
        for (auto const &i : boost::counting_range(1, 13))
        //for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            strKey.Format(_T("Month%d"), i);
            // AJT v17.1.3 Now use our own methods
            m_aryDateTrans[DATE_TRANS_MONTH].Add(GetStringFromTranslationINI(_T("Months"), strKey));
            m_aryDateTrans[DATE_TRANS_MONTH_SHORT].Add(GetStringFromTranslationINI(_T("MonthsAbbreviated"), strKey));
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `for` loops I had then set to **0 - 6** and **1 - 12** respectively. I found out that they had to be **0 - 7** and **1 - 13**. It iterates **UPTO** the last number, it doe snot include the last number itself!

So this is misleading:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html

Please confirm.

Comment: From [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/concepts/overview.html): "A Range provides iterators for accessing a half-open range [first,one_past_last) of elements..." This fits with how you iterate in c++ in general -- e.g. containers give you `begin()` and `end()`, and you don't dereference the end iterator. | To be honest, seeing `for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)` in c++ is a bit odd to me -- I'd expect `for(int i(0); i < 7; ++i)`.

Comment: Thanks. You have a link to that?

Comment: It's in the comment - the second word. In the docs it's "Range Concepts > Overview".

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks.